# Unit test an angular controller and service which uses a promise?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I cannot get the test result to pass I'm using a very basic implementation to understand testing deeper.

I have a factory which returns a promise, accessed from my controller. I want to test that the call succeeds and assigns the response to the `repos` var. Following is the code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .factory('searchServ', function ($timeout, $q, $http) {
    return {
      fetch: function(user) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function(){
          $http({method: 'GET', url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + user + '/repos'}).then(function(repos) {
            deferred.resolve(repos.data);
          }, function(reason){
            deferred.reject(reason.status);
            console.log(reason);
          });
        }, 30);

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, searchServ) {
    $scope.results = function(user) {
      $scope.message = '';
      searchServ.fetch(user).then(function (repos) {
        if(repos.length){
          $scope.message = '';
          $scope.repos = repos;
        }
        else{
          $scope.message = 'not found'
        }
      }, function (){
        $scope.message = 'not found';
      });
    };
  });

//Test

'use strict';

describe('MainCtrl', function () {
  var scope, searchServ, controller, deferred, repos = [{name: 'test'}];
  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q) {
    searchServ = {
      fetch: function () {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
    spyOn(searchServ, 'fetch').andCallThrough();
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      fetchGithub: fetchGithub
    });


  }));
  it('should test', function () {
    expect(scope.test).toEqual('ha');
  });

  it('should bind to scope', function () {
    scope.results();
    scope.$digest();
    expect(scope.message).toEqual('');
    //expect(scope.repos).not.toBe(undefined);
  });
});
```

Running the test gives me the following error :

> `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'spyOn(searchServ, 'fetch').andCallThrough()') in test/spec/controllers/main.js (line 15)`

Any idea how I can test this such that it tests the scope binding as well as the async call?

Comment: There's no `andCallThrough`. It is `and.callThrough`. You're extensively using [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern). Which will turn out badly in your case. Because searchServ.fetch returns unresolved promise in your case.

Comment: I've tried the and.callThrough but it always returns undefined, I was also trying another approach , like this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/upoc0ott/2/ but still get undefined, would be amazing if someone can help me out using either way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code.

I've created **[this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7xbK2sdDs8hIidRSLmeT?p=preview)** for the purpose. `index.js` is the file with your code and test cases. I've edited most of the part according to the conventions and best-practices.

There are a few pointers I wanted to give you:

- Since `$http` returns a promise, you should use that, instead of resolving the promise and creating another promise from your method. Not sure why is timeout used. So I removed `$q` and `$timeout` from `searchServ`'s dependencies.
- I did the same in the test case by removing the `deferred` variable that you used.
- You should be using `angular-mocks.js` to mock your services and other dependencies instead of defining a service inside your test case(The way you have did.)
- You should create separate `describe` blocks for testing different parts of your code(a `controller` in this case).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was a brilliant answer! Thank you so much for taking the time. I used $timeout and $q because they are promise based calls and if you generate a factory/service via yeoman it will give you that approach but since $http also returns a promise I think it works just as well! : )